# SignalR: Generated proxy vs. dynamically created hub file

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, signalr

Is the output from the SignalR hub proxy generator essentially the same as the dynamically generated hub proxy file? If not, what are the differences?

Some background on my question: I am struggling creating the hub proxy using the command line tool due to dependency issues during execution and I do think obtaining the dynamically generated file might be an easier way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated [on this ASP.NET page](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) about using hubs with SignalR:

> The generated proxy and what it does for you
>
> You can program a JavaScript client to communicate with a SignalR
>   service with or without a proxy that SignalR generates for you. What
>   the proxy does for you is **simplify the syntax** of the code you use to
>   connect, write methods that the server calls, and call methods on the
>   server.
>
> When you write code to call server methods, the generated proxy
>   enables you to use syntax that looks as though you were executing a
>   local function: you can write serverMethod(arg1, arg2) instead of
>   invoke('serverMethod', arg1, arg2). The generated proxy syntax also
>   **enables an immediate and intelligible client-side error if you mistype
>   a server method name**. And if you manually create the file that defines
>   the proxies, you can also get IntelliSense support for writing code
>   that calls server methods.

**To make long story short:**

This makes your life easier with real JS errors if you mistype SignalR hubs or method names.

**With** proxy:

```js
var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;
contosoChatHubProxy.client.addContosoChatMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
};
```

**Without** proxy:

```js
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
```

If you need to **generate the Proxy file** once instead of generating it at runtime, you can follow [this section](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy), which allows you generate it beforehand (for caching or bundling behavior).

Comment: In your reference there is a section called *"How to create a physical file for the SignalR generated proxy"*. My question targets exactly this physical output of the process (e.g. the generated JavaScript-file which I can physically access on my harddrive): Is this the same as the dynamically generated runtime JavaScript file available through `<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly; updated my answer to reflect question needs.

Comment: This does not work for AspNetCore sites.  SignalR.exe is unable to generate a proxy from exe/dlls like they did in the article.

Comment: This question was related to SignalR running against the full .Net framework. This [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1#hub-proxies) for SignalR Core states _Hub proxies are no longer automatically generated_